# IF Statement being Ignored - SQL Server

Tags: sql, if-statement

I have a 2008 R2 SQL Server that is used very sporadically so I've created a scheduled task that calls a very basic stored procedure to put the server to sleep if no one is logged in (by means of an IF() function)... this is the stored procedure;

```
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_GoToSleep] Script Date: 07/21/2013 13:53:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:   <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GoToSleep]
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT
a.loginame AS LoginName

FROM master.sys.sysprocesses AS a

WHERE
loginame NOT LIKE '%XXXX%'
AND hostname <> ''

GROUP BY
db_name(dbid)
, loginame
, hostname

UNION ALL

SELECT 
a.LogonName AS LoginName    

FROM XXXXDB.dbo.CurrentUser AS a)

BEGIN   
EXEC xp_cmdshell "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0"
END

END
```

The problem I'm having is the EXEC statement getting called when users are logged in and data should exist. There is nothing else putting the PC to sleep (stays on when the script is disabled).
Everything is being run from the same local account that has sufficient permissions which I verified by logging in via RDP under that account and checking that I get expected results when a user is logged in (just me at the moment).
The task is set to run when the local account is logged off and that appears to be when the issue starts...

Is there something here I'm missing? The IF function HAS to be initiating the EXEC statement but I KNOW the there should be data that would otherwise stop it - unless SQL is somehow returning different results when the account is logged off?
Would love some suggestions on this because it's got me tearing my hair out :-)

**UPDATE:** If it makes any difference, the task scheduler is calling the sp via sqlcmd - I figure this side of things is working because there's no doubting the sp is being initiated.

Comment: What's the CurrentUser object? I can't run the 2nd portion, `invalid object` just curious.

Comment: CurrentUser is part of a commercial software package I have...  it just retains a log of the current logons for licensing purposes.

It's not essential to the code - and the issue still occurs without it.